# Closes when sms is received?

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver

I was trying to display a message when you receive a sms "UPDATE". But my app force closes.
giving the code and the Log cat. I was testing it from emulators in eclipse. The sms is being received but does not display the "HI" message when "UPDATE" is received.
Please help!!

SrvSmsListener.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class SrvSmsListener extends Service 
{


private BroadcastReceiver IncomingSMSReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    private static final String SMS_RECEIVED =
            "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context _context, Intent _intent) {
        if (_intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            Bundle bundle = _intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");

                SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++)
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage
                            .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                for (SmsMessage message : messages) {
                    String strPhoneNo = message.getOriginatingAddress();
                    String msg = message.getMessageBody();

                    if (msg.startsWith("UPDATE"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got it", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // this stops notifications to others


                        this.abortBroadcast();
                        // do what you want

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public void onCreate() {
    final String SMS_RECEIVED = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(SMS_RECEIVED);
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = IncomingSMSReceiver;
    registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (IncomingSMSReceiver != null)
    {
        unregisterReceiver(IncomingSMSReceiver);
    }
}

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main extends MapActivity implements LocationListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
MapView map;
long start;
long stop;
int x, y;
GeoPoint touchedPoint;
Drawable d;
List<Overlay> overlayList;
LocationManager lm;
String towers;
int lat ;
int longi; 





@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, SrvSmsListener.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mv);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    Touchy t = new Touchy();
    overlayList = map.getOverlays();
    overlayList.add(t);

    d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pinn);

    //Placing pintpoint
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria crit = new Criteria();

    towers = lm.getBestProvider(crit, false);
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(towers);

    if (location != null){
        lat = (int) (location.getLatitude() *1E6);
        longi= (int) (location.getLongitude() *1E6);



        GeoPoint ourLocation = new GeoPoint(lat,longi);
        OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(ourLocation, "Hi!!", "2nd");
        CustomPinPoint custom = new CustomPinPoint(d, Main.this);   
        custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
        overlayList.add(custom);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Couldnt get provider", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }





}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPause();
    lm.removeUpdates(this);
}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onResume();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(towers, 500, 1, this );
}


    @Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}



class Touchy extends Overlay{
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e, MapView m){
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        start = e.getEventTime();

    }
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        stop = e.getEventTime();
        x = (int) e.getX();
        y = (int) e.getY();
        touchedPoint = map.getProjection().fromPixels(x, y);

    }
    if (stop - start > 1500){
        AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("Pick Option");


        alert.setButton("Hello", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(touchedPoint, "Hi!!", "2nd");
                CustomPinPoint custom = new CustomPinPoint(d, Main.this);   
                custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
                overlayList.add(custom);



        }
        });
        alert.setButton3("Get Address", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try{
                List<Address> address = geocoder.getFromLocation(touchedPoint.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6, touchedPoint.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6 , 1);
                if (address.size() > 0){
                    String display = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i<address.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){

                        display += address.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                    }
                    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), display, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    t.show();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
            }
        }});
        alert.setButton2("Toggle View", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                if (map.isSatellite()){
                    map.setSatellite(false);
                    map.setStreetView(true);
                }else{
                    map.setStreetView(false);
                    map.setSatellite(true);
                }
            }
});
        alert.setButton("Place a Pin", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(touchedPoint, "Hi!!", "2nd");
                CustomPinPoint custom = new CustomPinPoint(d, Main.this);   
                custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
                overlayList.add(custom);

            }


        });
        alert.show();
        return true;
    }

        return false;
    }

}



public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    lat = (int) (l.getLatitude() *1E6);
    longi = (int) (l.getLongitude() *1E6);
    GeoPoint ourLocation = new GeoPoint(lat,longi);
    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(ourLocation, "Hi!!", "2nd");
    CustomPinPoint custom = new CustomPinPoint(d, Main.this);   
    custom.insertPinpoint(overlayItem);
    overlayList.add(custom);

}




public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}




public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

CustomPinPoint.java

```
public class CustomPinPoint extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

private ArrayList<OverlayItem> pinpoints = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
private Context c;

public CustomPinPoint(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenter(defaultMarker));
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public CustomPinPoint(Drawable m, Context context ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this(m);
    c = context;
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pinpoints.get(i);
}

@Override
public int size() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pinpoints.size();
}


public void insertPinpoint(OverlayItem item){
    pinpoints.add(item);
    this.populate();
}
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.mehul.googlemaps"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name">   

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
         <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:enabled="true"
        android:name=".SrvSmsListener" />
    <receiver android:name=".IncomingSMSReceiver"> 
    <intent-filter> 
        <action android:name=
            "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Log cat

```
04-08 16:44:57.054: W/dalvikvm(311): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   instantiate receiver com.mehul.googlemaps.IncomingSMSReceiver:   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mehul.googlemaps.IncomingSMSReceiver in loader   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.mehul.googlemaps-2.apk]
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2789)
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3200(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2083)
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mehul.googlemaps.IncomingSMSReceiver in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.mehul.googlemaps-2.apk]
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2780)
04-08 16:44:57.244: E/AndroidRuntime(311):  ... 10 more
```

Comment: just register your IncomingSMSReceiver in Manifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are registering service as a receiver for your application.register broadcast receiver IncomingSMSReceiver for listening sms.  Change this :

```
<receiver android:name=".SrvSmsListener"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name=
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

to

```
<receiver android:name=".SrvSmsListener.IncomingSMSReceiver"> 
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name=
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

Comment: @MehulRastogi : you have SmsReceiver.java in your project?

Comment: but u have somewhere bez catlog error says SmsReceiver class not found plz build and clean your project

Comment: use` <receiver android:name=".SrvSmsListener.IncomingSMSReceiver"> `

Comment: Still same thing.. what can be the problem maan!!

Answer (score 0):

The Receiver class you specify in your AndroidManifest must extend BroadcastReceiver. In your case you specify:

```
<receiver android:name=".SrvSmsListener">
```

But this class extends Service:

```
public class SrvSmsListener extends Service
```

Comment: So i should change Service to BroadcastReceiver. only this..?

Comment: Well that should resolve the immediate crash. Once you change the class you will need to make some updates and move the onReceive(). After that you should at least be able to receive the broadcast.

Comment: I am receiving the message but the HI message is not being displayed.

Comment: Is this after changing the class to a BroadcastReceiver? If you are sure the broadcast is triggering your receiver (ie. code is entering the onReceive() portion of your receiver) then I would just use the eclipse debugger to step through the onReceive() code to see why the HI message section is not being reached.

Comment: Oh and if you resolved the initial stack trace in your question and are getting another stack trace (or have anything interesting in your logs) post it up.

Answer (score 0):

That code is mine ;)

you must add your service in manifest:

```
 <service
            android:enabled="true"
            android:name=".SrvSmsListener" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public class Sms2Activity extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

String message,number;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    Toast.makeText(context, "incomming message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //Get values from Bundle - get incoming number


    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[ ] msgs = null;
    String str = "";
    if (bundle != null)
    {





        //---retrieve the received message here ---
        Object[ ] pdus = (Object[ ]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
        for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
        {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[ ])pdus[i]);
            str += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            str += " :";
            str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            str += "\n";
            message = msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            number = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        }
       // ........first show sms here.....
       Toast.makeText(context, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 



   }
```

Comment: If i send a message UPDATE will it show me a text msg HI and will it give any notification to the user.

Comment: this code is t0 detect incoming message  in your comment it is about sending sms but my code is about the incoming sms.if u dont want to show the incoming message notification just add abortboardcast on the if condition